# How to get text from SearchView in Cursor

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-search

Ive succesfully put search-suggestions to my app and right now do i need to find out, how to get the typed text from SearchView to my Cursor. I know onQueryTextChange(String) method, but how do i get the text right in my contentprovider class?

Comment: in ContentProvider.query() you create the Cursor, you dont read it

Comment: Yes, it creates, but my provider is different class than my main activity, so how do i put my text there?

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html